# Label top distance issue without navigation bar and Status Bar with iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view controller where I need to hide the status bar and navigation bar because of UI requirement. I have hid the status bar and navigation bar and added a label with a top constraint of 20 pixels from the top. It looks fine with iPhone 6 and other devices but in case of iPhone X, label is not at a distance of 20 pixels. How to fix this?

Comment: make sure you give the constraints from safe area layout.

Comment: please add screenshot , But this issue check the constraint top link with safe area or super view ?

Answer (score 0):

There is Safe Area included in the bottom and top of the screen of new iphones like Iphone X.

You can use this if your using constaints

```
    myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Or if you are defining frame for label you can do such like this

```
    myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top + 20, width: view.frame.width, height: 30)
```